# Why does client.guilds.cache.size only say "0" in my playing status even if it's in 2 servers?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

i have seen many people who had trouble with `client.guilds.size` but I switched to the recently suggested `client.guilds.cache.size`. In my playing status, it only says `"WATCHING my prefix | 0 servers."` same happens for trying to fetch the member count and channel count.

```
let activities = [ `${client.guilds.cache.size} servers`, `${client.channels.cache.size} channels`, `${client.users.cache.size} users` ], i = 0;

setInterval(() => client.user.setActivity(`${prefix}help | ${activities[i ++ % activities.length]}`, { type: "WATCHING"}),`${process.env.INTERVAL}`)
```

This is the script I am using to achieve that.
I already have an Eval command, that returns 2 aswell.

I can't seem to find a solution to this somehow.
I hope you can help me, if you need anything, tell me!

Comment: Where do you have this code snippet?

Comment: Do you update `activities` each time, or it is only set at the start of the program?

Comment: @Syntle i tried multiple locations, but the `let activities` is at the top, where all the consts are and the `setInterval()` comes directly after.

Comment: @theusaf its only set at the start of the program...
how do i update that then?

Comment: You can use `activities = [ \`${client.guilds.cache.size} servers\`, \`${client.channels.cache.size} channels\`, \`${client.users.cache.size} users\` ]` in the interval function, or put it on a separate interval. Basically, just keep getting the cache when you change your status.

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is that your `client` has not logged in before you grab the `guilds` collection

You need to place that code inside your `ready` event.

```js
client.on('ready', () => {
  let activities = [ `${client.guilds.cache.size} servers`, `${client.channels.cache.size} channels`, `${client.users.cache.size} users` ], i = 0;

  setInterval(() => client.user.setActivity(`${prefix}help | ${activities[i ++ % activities.length]}`, { type: "WATCHING"}),`${process.env.INTERVAL}`)
})
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I combined the suggestion of you and theusaf to make it work now! Thank you.