# I made a command for the bot to display all the members, text channels and servers he's "Serving", but it returns me with a value of 0

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I tried making a `&bot-info` command to display the amount of members / channels / servers the bot is in, but every time i use the command it displays "0" for each value

```js
    const Discord = require('discord.js')
    const client = new Discord.Client();
    async function execute(message, args) {
        const servers = await client.guilds.cache.size
        const users = await client.users.cache.size
        const textchannels = await client.channels.cache.size
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            
            .setTitle('Bot Stats')
            .setColor('#000000')
            .addFields(
                {
                    name: ' Servers',
                    value: `Serving ${servers} servers.`,
                    inline: true
                },
                {
                    name: ' Channels',
                    value: `Serving ${textchannels} channels.`,
                    inline: true
                },
                {
                    name: ' Server Users',
                    value: `Serving ${users}`,
                    inline: true
                }
            )
            

        await message.channel.send(embed)
    }
module.exports = {
    name: 'bot-info',
    description: 'bot information',
    execute
}
```

Message that the bot displays

[image: Message that the bot displays]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61980179/why-does-client-guilds-cache-size-only-say-0-in-my-playing-status-even-if-its

Comment: @Phix that does not apply here, because this code is being run when the `message` event triggers and the bot would already be ready by the point that it is able to receive message events (and therefore, the `ready` event would already have triggered).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are creating a new client. `client` is an object that essentially represents your bot. You've already created a client in your main js file (server.js or index.js), and in this file you are creating another client. The client you have created in this file is *an entirely new bot*, and it is a bot that is not logged in (hence why it show zeroes across the board).

Instead of creating a new `Discord.Client` object, you need to use the same one that was used in your main file. Luckily, the `message` object has a `message.client` property which is a reference to your main `client` object, the client that instantiated the `message`. Here's an example of how that would look in your code:

```
//Removed "const Discord" and "const client" from the top of this file

async function execute(message, args) {
    const client = message.client;

    const servers = await client.guilds.cache.size;
    const users = await client.users.cache.size;
    const textchannels = await client.channels.cache.size;
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        
        .setTitle('Bot Stats')
        .setColor('#000000')
        .addFields(
            {
                name: ' Servers',
                value: `Serving ${servers} servers.`,
                inline: true
            },
            {
                name: ' Channels',
                value: `Serving ${textchannels} channels.`,
                inline: true
            },
            {
                name: ' Server Users',
                value: `Serving ${users}`,
                inline: true
            }
        )
        

    await message.channel.send(embed)
}
```

Relevant resources:
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=client