# Is client.guilds.cache.size broken?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to make it so that my discord bot displays how many servers it's on as its status, but when i do client.guilds.cache.size it just says 0. This was happening with my friend aswell.

Here's my code if it's of any use...

```
const fs = require('fs');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { prefix, token } = require('./myconfig10.json');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const request = require('request');
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
const embedAuthor = ('This bot was made by <my discord name>')
const servers = client.guilds.cache.size


//Telling the bot where to look for the commands
for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

//Once the bot is up and running, display 'Ready' in the console
client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
    client.user.setActivity(`on ${servers}`);
});

//Seeing if the message starts with the prefix
client.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

//Telling the bot what arguments are
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/)
    const commandName = args.shift().toLowerCase();

//Checking to see if the command you sent is one of the commands in the commands folder 
    if (!client.commands.has(commandName)) return;
    console.log(`Collected 1 Item, ${message}`)

    const command = client.commands.get(commandName);

//Try to execute the command.
    try {
        command.execute(message, args);
    
//If there's an error, don't crash the bot. 
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        
//Sends a message on discord telling you there was an error
        message.reply('there was an error trying to execute that command!');
```

and it says:

[Its says 'Playing on 0' on my bot's status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ge31.png)

Comment: Have you turned on intents from the [discord developer portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications)?

Comment: @Tyler2P I'm not sure what that is?

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64559390/none-of-my-discord-js-guildmember-events-are-emitting-my-user-caches-are-basica/64559391#64559391) could help.

Comment: @Tyler2P I've checked both of them but it still says 0, will it take a bit to take effect?

Comment: The issue is not intents. The problem is that you are trying to grab the `guilds` collection before the client is ready. You need to move the code that gets `client.guilds.cache.size` into your `ready` event handler. See the answer to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61980179/why-does-client-guilds-cache-size-only-say-0-in-my-playing-status-even-if-its)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are trying to grab the `guilds` collection before the `client` is ready. You need to move the code that gets `client.guilds.cache.size` into your `ready` event handler.

```
client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
    client.user.setActivity(`on ${client.guilds.cache.size}`);
});
```

Relevant resources:
[Why does client.guilds.cache.size only say "0" in my playing status even if it's in 2 servers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61980179/why-does-client-guilds-cache-size-only-say-0-in-my-playing-status-even-if-its)